# <pre> tag messing with UI

Tags: php, html

I returning my data to build a list group. All is fine but when the data contains `<pre>` tag it messes my display.

My list group as follows.

```
if (isset($BS_array)){

      //Create a list group to show results
      echo '<div class="list-group">';

      foreach($BS_array as $result){

        ?>

         <!-- Build list group -->
         <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" aria-current="true">
          <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <!-- Incident number goes here -->
            <h5 style="cursor: pointer;" id="<?php echo $result['number']; ?>" onclick="getINCDetails(this.id)" class="mb-1"><?php echo $result['number']; ?></h5>
          </div>
          <!-- Description goes here -->
          <p class="mb-1"><?php echo $result['description']; ?></p>
          <small>

          <?php

          //List BS in INC card
          echo $result['state'];

          ?>
          </small>
        </div>

        <?php
  } 
  echo '</div>';
}

?>
```

The way when all goes ok should be like this.
[image: correct]

But at times, `$result['description']`, contains the word `<pre>`, which messes things up.
It will look like this.

[image: not right]

How do I fix/circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont require html tags to actually work on the description just use htmlentities():

```
<?php echo htmlentities($result['description']); ?>
```

That will actually show  instead of the browser considering it html tag.

Comment: Okay, that works wonderfully. I did not even know such thing exists. Thank you very much for your help.